# Why is it a bad idea to run more processes than your processor core count?

Tags: parallel-processing, operating-system

For example, I have a machine with 2 Cores. Let's say I have a queue of tasks to clear using a program called `ninja`.

What one of the following would do the job faster which is to clear all the tasks from the queue.

1. `./ninja &`
   `./ninja &`

or

running ninja more than my core count

2. `./ninja &`
   `./ninja &`
   `./ninja &`
   `./ninja &`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is easier to think about if you consider have huge numbers of tasks to do.  How many you should run depends on what the processes are actually doing.

If all the processes are compute bound, take an equal amount of time, and don't consume the entire memory when they are run in parallel, you want the live process count at any moment to match the core count.   That way each core runs for an equal amount of time without any need to context switch to other processors.

If the number of live processes at any moment exceeds the memory availability of your machine, and they are computing, you'll just force a lot of paging and that will hurt your runtime badly.

If the processes are doing lots of I/O and getting stuck waiting for events, (disk data reads,  input devices,  output-buffer-full blocking), then you want a lot more live processes so that there are processes avaialbe to do work when other processes are blocked.

If the processes vary in memory demand size, you'll want to run the biggest processes first and fill memory with processes that have lesser memory demand.  This is often hard to do because you often don't know the memory demand of each process.   If you have lots and lots of tasks, you can greedily run one big one and as many little ones as fits, and statistically you'll probably do pretty well.

If you have only a small number of them (you show 4), you can simply try the combinations and see.

Comment: Thanks. The processes run well under my 4GB RAM. So, I will just go with 1 process/core.